# TypeError: str_replace(): Argument must be of type array|string, null given

Tags: php, exception, php8.1

I am getting the below error:

```
main.CRITICAL: TypeError: str_replace(): Argument #3 ($subject) must be of type array|string, null given
```

In the following code:

```
public function beforeSendResponse(Http $subject)
    {
        if ($this->ampService->isAmp()) {
            return;
        }

        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();

        if (!$this->configProvider->getGeneralIsEnable($store) && !$this->configProvider->getIsPixelEnabled($store)) {
            return;
        }

        $content = $subject->getContent();

        if ($this->configProvider->getGeneralIsEnable($store)) {
            $regularCode = $this->configProvider->getGeneralRegularCode($store);

            $subject->setContent(
                str_replace('</head>', $regularCode . "\n</head>", $content)
            );
        }

        if ($this->configProvider->getIsPixelEnabled($store)) {
            $regularCode = $this->configProvider->getPixelCode($store);

            $subject->setContent(
                str_replace('</head>', $regularCode . "\n</head>", $content)
            );
        }

        if (!empty($this->configProvider->getPixelDomainVerification($store))) {
            $regularCode = $this->configProvider->getPixelDomainVerification($store);

            $subject->setContent(
                str_replace('</head>', $regularCode . "\n</head>", $content)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

No written by me. It seems that with **php8.1** line:

```
str_replace('</head>', $regularCode . "\n</head>", $content)
```

throw error:

```
 main.CRITICAL: TypeError: str_replace(): Argument #3 ($subject) must be of type array|string, null given
```

As I inspect this code tries to put javascript code to the footer before send a request. It is uses in a custom module for GTM

Now sure how to fix it.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **$content = $subject->getContent();** by the following line:

```
$content = $subject->getContent() ?? '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with:

```
str_replace((string) '</head>', $regularCode . "\n</head>", $content)
```